# Angularjs $http.post fails to work in android app but works in simulator

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an app to run on android devices.
I am using Visual Studio 2015 with ng-Cordova, ionic framework and angularjs

To fetch data following code (in angular controller) connects with Web Api (developed in Visual Studio and hosted in a website)

```
//OnSubmit of the form
$scope.submit = function () {
    alert("I am here");
    $http.post('<webapi address>', $scope.item).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             alert("Success")
            // play with data
        }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("error");
        alert(status);
    })
};
```

Index.html contains ng-model="item.mytext"

app.js $scope.item contains the html text box values

Config.xml contains reference to cordova-plugin-whitelist and its all relevant allow-intent href

Android manifest-xml contains uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

If I run the whole code in android simulator, it works with success with alert("Success") and I get the data from Web API

But as an app in adroid device, on submit button click it goes to $scope.submit with alert("I am here").
Then it fails on $http.post with alert("error"). As such no error is generated and all params data, status, headers, config are undefined.

I have tried this also $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; but without success.

I have tried all info given by answers to somewhat similar questions here but without success.

Kindly help.

Comment: Can you check your project in your browser using ionic serve command.

Comment: May i know your hosted site wrote in php or other?

Comment: Did you get any error msg? Please use this "alert(JSON.stringify(status))"

Comment: @cfprabhu No error message. status is undefined. Also project is working in browser. I have not checked with ionic serve command as I do not know how to use it! Also the website is written in Visual Studio 2015. It is working. Hosted web api is written in VS and it is hosted as subdomain.website.com

Comment: Please check your app using by ionic serve

Comment: It is very easy. Its occurred by cross origin issue.

Comment: I tested with ionic serve but same result, i.e. no error generated but it is unable to execute $http.post. Menwhile I also installed and enabled CORS in Web API. But this angularjs http.post did not work

Comment: Did you inject the $http on your controller?

Comment: Can i see your controller?

Comment: myl.controller('MyLatCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.item = {
        text1: "",
        text2: ""
    }

    //OnSubmit of the form
    $scope.submit = function () {
        alert("I am here");
        $http.post('<webapi address>', $scope.item).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             alert("Success")
            // play with data
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("error");
            alert(status);
       })
    };
});

Comment: It had everything to do with content-security-policy in index.html. Changing default-src 'self' to default-src 'self' <webapi subdomain> solved. Thanks @cfprabhu. The problem is solved